# Why when a .bat file tests for %ERRORLEVEL% after running .NET app, it is testing for a string return type, not an int?

Tags: .net, exit, return-type, batch-file

I was looking at how to run a .NET app from the command line, or in a bat file, and this code was given for testing the %ERRORLEVEL% (the exiting return value) of the application:

```
@if "%ERRORLEVEL%" == "0" goto success
```

Why is it testing for "0" and not 0? As I understand it, the .NET executable is returning an int when it exits, not a string.

Comment: That doesn't look right to me.

Comment: That's what I thought. But it's in the book _Pro C# 2008 and the .NET 3.5 Platform_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just coercing the numeric value to a string and comparing.  This can be helpful if an environment variable has no value so %PARAM% == 1 would evaluate to  == 1 which would cause an error.

For checking a program's ERRORLEVEL, it's better to evaluate as per [Raymond Chen's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/09/26/8965755.aspx).

```
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 ECHO error level is 1 or more
```

Comment: @Avilo: When you say "coercing the numeric value to a string", is that like an implicit cast? Also, I'm not sure I understand your example - "so %PARAM% == 1 would evaluate to == 1 which would cause an error."

Comment: @Richard: if %PARAM% is not set, `%PARAM% == 1` is the same as `== 1` (there's no value for %PARAM%), which obviously is not valid syntax. But `"%PARAM%" == "1"` becomes `"" == "1"`, which is valid syntax, and false, like desired.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I think this was just me not understanding how bat file sytax works. So there isn't really a "cast" from an int value %ERRORLEVEL% to a string value, it's more like you are wrapping the int value in %ERRORLEVEL% with quotes which is turning it into a string for the comparison to "1"?

Comment: @Richard: yeah, something like that. It works because variables are replaced even inside strings.